# Find first sequence of numbers in a string?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So first of all i would like to clear things off by saying that this is for a Minecraft plugin. So I have a method to spawn some mobs (You dont know what mobs it is), and give them custom names. The names are based on numbers. But I also have a sequence of characters in its name. So for instance if the name for the mob was "355 Blaze" it would return an int of 355, and cut the rest out. How should I do this? Currently I use substring but it doesnt work as if the number goes above 9 it will return the first number only.

Comment: If it's returning the first digit only, you're using the wrong parameters for `substring`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If its separated by space, use substring based on the location of first space:

```
Integer mobId = new Integer(fullMobName.substring(0, fullMobName.indexOf(" ")));
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a regex.

```
private final static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

static String firstNum(String s) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    return m.find() ? m.group() : null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex expression in replace method

```
   String s = "355 Blaze";
   s.replaceAll("[A-Za-z\\s]+", "");
```

Then you can cast to int.

Answer (score 2):

Do it without a regex (assuming the number is positive and fits in an `int`):

```
int i = 0;
// Skip past non-digits.
while (i < s.length() && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
  ++i;
}
if (i < s.length()) {
  int num = 0;
  // Accumulate the digits into the result.
  while (i < s.length() && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
    num = 10 * num + Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
    ++i;
  }
  return num;
}
// No digits found.
throw new NoSuchElementException("No digits found!");
```

Answer (score 1):

If it only contains digits followed by letters( with possibly an optional space), this will also work:

```
String ss[] =  original.split("a-zA-Z ]", 2);
//ss[0] contains the numbers
```